# Animating GTK+ Windows

Tags: c, animation, gtk

I am trying to create a smoothly animated window in GTK+
Here is the code I came up with:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
  GtkWindow *window;
  int timePassed;
  int fromX;
  int fromY;
  int toX;
  int toY;
  int time;
  int step;
  void (*callback)(void*);
  void *data;
} AnimationStructure;

double coolBezier(double t) {
  double register one_minus_t_powered;
  double register one_minus_t_;

  one_minus_t_ = 1 - t;
  one_minus_t_powered = one_minus_t_ * one_minus_t_;

  return one_minus_t_powered * 0.0 + one_minus_t_ * 2.0 * t * -1.00 + t * t * 1.0;
}

gboolean animate_window_timeout(AnimationStructure *ani) {
  double time = coolBezier((double) ani->timePassed / ani->time);

  if (time >= 1.0) {
    gtk_window_move(ani->window, ani->fromX + ani->toX, ani->fromY + ani->toY);
    ani->callback(ani->data);
    g_free(ani);
    return FALSE;
  }

  printf("FromX: %d; FromY: %d\n", ani->fromX, ani->fromY);

  gtk_window_move(ani->window, ani->fromX + (ani->toX * time), ani->fromY + (ani->toY * time));

  ani->timePassed += ani->step;

  return TRUE;
}

void animate_window(GtkWindow *window, int x, int y, int time, int step_time, void (*callback)(void*), void* data) {
  AnimationStructure *ani = g_new(AnimationStructure, 1);

  ani->window = window;
  ani->toX = x;
  ani->toY = y;
  ani->timePassed = 0;
  ani->time = time;
  ani->step = step_time;
  ani->callback = callback;
  ani->data = data;

  gtk_window_get_position(window, &(ani->fromX), &(ani->fromY));

  g_timeout_add(step_time, (GSourceFunc) animate_window_timeout, ani);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWindow *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = (GtkWindow*) gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(window, GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(window, 300, 300);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

  animate_window(window, 300, 0, 1000, 15, NULL, NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

This works and when I applied it to the notification window the effect was like on this gif: [image: Animated notification window]
But the window is not smooth as I would like it to be, you can notice that at the end the window almost jumps 50px from left to right.

Comment: `one_minus_t_powered * 0.0` looks weird, are you sure it's correct ? Otherwise here's some reading on how gnome-shell got 60fps synchronization: https://blog.fishsoup.net/2009/05/28/frames-not-idles/ and https://blog.fishsoup.net/2011/06/22/what-to-do-if-you-cant-do-60fps/

Comment: You’re right, (0.0 + one_minus_t_) is not necessary. This is just a quadratic bezier function stripped from the x (time) value that I didn't use anyway, with hard-coded values. something like cubic-bezier(0,-1,1,1) in CSS.